# Selecting Distinct Embedded Objects by their Properties

Tags: java, spring

Utilizing [Spring Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) API, how can I retrieve the `DISTINCT` properties of an embedded `Object`? Take a `User` object for example; how can I select all the distinct `Department` objects based on distinct Department names in the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.department from User u (based on Department name)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts?

Answer (score 2):

> @Query(select distinct u from User u where u.name=:name)

I think this would return what you are looking for @Kurai

Answer (score 2):

You would need similar this...Try..Good luck

```
select distinct <object_property> from <tablename>
```